# Can't access certain websites

Tags: macos, networking, dns, osx-mountain-lion

I'm trying to access the site http://www.svenskadomaner.se but it's unreachable from my MacBook Pro (OSX 10.8.5). The domain belongs to a web hosting company and it's not only this specific site I can't reach but all sites on their servers.

What I've tried/checked:

- Different browsers
- Different connections (home, work, friends - i.e. different ISPs)
- Different user profiles
- Firewall (turned off)
- No AV programs (as what I can see)
- Checked /etc/hosts
- Flush DNS
- Changed to Google's DNS
- Apache server isn't running in the background
- Ping svenskadomaner.se (Request timeout)
- Traceroute svenskadomaner.se (stops at first step)
- Update to Mavericks

**Note:** Accessing the sites through a proxy site works.

I'm really out of options here. What is the next thing to try?

Comment: What's the output of the ping and traceroute?  Do you see the name resolving to an IP? What if you try accessing directly via the IP address?

Comment: @ernie: With ping I get the ip (5.150.255.189) but then "Request timeout"

Comment: The site comes up for me, but ping times out. Ping might be blocked. Or ICMP might be blocked, which could cause MTU issues and prevent you from loading the site I imagine.

Comment: @Tanner: Ok, that may be the problem. I've tried to change MTU down to 1280 without any luck. Do you have any ideas how to solve the problem?

Comment: Contact your ISP, mention that you are able to access domain through proxy server but cannot access it directly. ISP should be able to resolve it for you.

Comment: @smc: But i'm having the same trouble on different connections (i.e different IPSs) so that shouldn't be the problem?

Comment: Do you have a different machine for the test purpose? It would be interesting to see if the problem follows your MacBook

Comment: Also (as ernie has suggested previously), try accessing website by IP address.

Comment: @smc: Yep, tried with my gfs MacBook and my iPad (both works). Tried to access the site with the ip (5.150.255.189) - no luck.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Macs'.  Do they have a hosts file?  You could see if there is something wonky there.  Have you tried restarting your system?  Also - I don't know how to do this on Mac, but try using a different DNS server: 4.4.4.4 is Google I believe and there is OpenDNS.  Also, try accessing it from *hidemyass.com*.  It's a web proxy.  If you can get there that way, that would point to something with your IP being blocked somehow.

Comment: @user1167442: Tried with hidemyass.com and it worked. A strange thing though is that I've tried several internet connection = different ip's.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, finally solved it!

I'm not really sure but I think the application LogMeIn was the problem. What I did was to remove some startup items in:

/Library/LaunchAgents

/Library/LaunchDaemons

I removed the plists for LogMeIn and GPGTools (I'm not using these anymore and will delete them completely) and restarted and it suddenly worked!

Comment: I don't know about on Mac, but on Windows, LogMeIn leaves behind gobs of leftover crap that can - and in your case likely did - cause all sorts of network problems.  Glad you got it working.  I had a similar problem a little while ago, and it was hard to detect, and a pain in the a$$ to solve.